# SQL Query Join Date Range on DateRange where they are overlapping

Tags: sql, date, join

I have table A:

```
UID_Panel   StartDate                   EndDate                     Available
3173        2014-07-14 00:00:00.000 2014-07-20 23:59:59.993     NULL
3173        2014-07-21 00:00:00.000 2014-07-27 23:59:59.993     NULL
3173        2014-07-28 00:00:00.000 2014-08-03 23:59:59.993     NULL
```

and Table B:

```
uid_panel   dte_down_from               dte_Down_To
3173            2014-07-21 00:00:00.000     2014-07-31 00:00:00.000
```

I need to do a join and mark the second two records' `Available` column with `No`. There will always be a mon-sun in table A and the down dates could be any random date range.  If the `startDate` and `EndDate` overlap the Downdates, it needs to be marked `No`.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you want an `update` or `select`.  Here is the `select` version:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from tableb b
                          where b.dte_down_from <= a.EndDate and
                                b.dte_down_to >= a.StartDate
                         )
             then 'No'
        end) as Available
from tableA a;
```

Note that this uses the `exists` clause in a `case` statement rather than a `join`.  There is the possibility that two down periods might overlap with one week, and this formulation ensures that rows are not accidentally multiplied by the `join`.

Also, this uses standard SQL.  You don't specify the database, but this should work in it.